# Interrupting an IPython kernel embedded in a QT4 widget

Tags: python, linux, qt, pyqt, ipython

I want to embed an Ipython terminal in a QT widget so I can access objects in my QT application. I understand that this is possible with examples such as this: https://github.com/gpoulin/python-test/blob/master/embedded_qtconsole.py
however, if the kernel is blocking (in an infinite while loop for example) the whole application is unresponsive and can only be killed with a keyboard interrupt from the terminal where the qt application was run. If I use the QtKernelManager instead of QtInProcessKernelManager I can successfully interrupt the kernel from the qt application, however, I cannot access objects within it as the kernel is embedded in a different process.
Is there a way to catch the keyboard interrupt when embedding the IPython terminal in the same process ? or should I use a different implementation of embedding the kernel ?

my adapted code is below

```
import os
os.environ['QT_API'] = 'pyqt'
import sip
sip.setapi("QString", 2)
sip.setapi("QVariant", 2)

import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore

from pkg_resources import require
require('ipython')

from IPython.qt.console.rich_ipython_widget import RichIPythonWidget
from IPython.qt.inprocess import QtInProcessKernelManager

class IPythonWidget(QtGui.QWidget):

    def __init__(self, **kwarg):
        super(IPythonWidget, self).__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def startIpKernel(self):
        self.kernel_manager = QtInProcessKernelManager()
        self.kernel_manager.start_kernel()
        self.kernel_manager.kernel.gui = 'qt4'
        self.kernel_client = kernel_client = self.kernel_manager.client()
        self.kernel_client.start_channels()

    def initUI(self):
        self.startIpKernel()
        self.addWidgets()

    def addWidgets(self):

        self.button = QtGui.QPushButton()
        self.button.setText("test button")

        self.console = RichIPythonWidget(self)
        self.console.kernel_manager =self.kernel_manager
        self.console.kernel_client = self.kernel_client
        self.console.kernel_manager.kernel.shell.push({"button": self.button})#this can be wrapped into another method

        vbox = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        vbox.addWidget(self.console)
        vbox.addWidget(self.button)
        self.setLayout(vbox)

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        self.mousepos = event.pos()

if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = IPythonWidget()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```